# executing a data-import function

Tags: function, import

I am learning python at the same time as I'm trying to do my work. When I use the following function to import some data (GSLIB is just a file format):

```
def ReadGsLibFile( infilename ) :
   file = open(infilename, 'r')
   file.readline()
   nvar = int(file.readline())
   for i in range(nvar) : file.readline()
   data = []
   while True :
      dataFile = file.readline()
      if len(dataFile) == 0 : break
      else :
        data.append( [float(val) val in dataFile.split() ]  )
   return data
```

I get this error:

```
File "", line 13
data.append( [float(val) val in dataFile.split() ] )
^
SyntaxError:invalid syntax
```

The data I am using looks like this:

```
apTItest.sgems
4
x
y
z
value
  0.00         0.00               0.00                 4.000000
  1.00         0.00               0.00                 4.000000
  2.00         0.00               0.00                 4.000000
  3.00         0.00               0.00                 4.000000
  4.00         0.00               0.00                 4.000000
  5.00         0.00               0.00                 4.000000
  6.00         0.00               0.00                 4.000000
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction to get past this error?

Answer (score 0):

problem fixed a different way - although i still don't get why the above does not work. It could be based on different versions of Python (2.7 vs 3.3). Also changed the input file format so it's easier to import.

```
def ReadGsLibFile( infilename ) :
    file = open(infilename, 'r')
    file.readline()
    nvar = int(file.readline())
    for i in range(nvar) : file.readline()
    data = []
    while True :
          dataFile = file.readline()
          if len(dataFile) == 0 : break
          else :
              row = []
              for val in dataFile.split():
                  row.append(float(val))

              data.extend(row)
    return data
```

and the import file now just keeps the last column in the original file, ... looks like this:

```
apTItest
4
x
y
z
value
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
```